# Redistributing Nuget References w/ Licenses

Tags: licensing, apache-license

I have a basic gap in my knowledge when it comes to open source licensing.

**I realize that the answers to this question aren't legally binding :)**.

With that being said, let's say I am writing a custom application for a client.  It will run on their infrastructure.

Assume that:

- I add a library to the project via NuGet.
- That library is using the Apache 2.0 license.
- I am not modifying the library at all - I am using it as is.

Do I need to provide a copy of the license in the source code?

Do I need to provide a copy of the license with the application binaries?

Comment: Have you read the license? What does it say? Apache 2.0 is fairly short and simple.

Comment: I can "copy, modify and distribute the covered software in source and/or binary forms".  And also "exercise patent rights that would normally only extend to the licensor provided that: all copies, modified or unmodified, are accompanied by a copy of the licence."

I am not trying to claim patent rights though.  So I don't think I need to copy the license.

Comment: @amon, "fairly short and simple", really?!!?? It's long and written in gobbledegook in my view. I just read it, and had no idea what the answer to Matt's question was. Then I read your answer, where you translate the gobbledegook into English and now I do understand :)

Comment: @DavidArno I may have exaggerated a bit ;-) But once we strip the lengthy definitions away, we are left with a reasonably concise legal text, on par with the Creative Commons base license. It's clearly much longer than the minimalistic MIT license, but quite enjoyable when compared with the monstrous GNU licenses, such as the GPLv3 or the GFDL…. Key to understanding the Apache license is that it's a liberal BSD-like license, but gives proper consideration to trademark and patent issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Apache 2.0 license](http://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0) lists under section 4. Redistribution:

> You may reproduce and distribute copies of the Work or Derivative Works […] in Source or Object form,
>   provided that You meet the following conditions:
>
> 1. You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License
>
> […]
>
> 3. You must retain, in the Source form of any Derivative Works that You distribute, all copyright, patent, trademark, and attribution notices from the Source form of the Work […]
>
> 4. If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its distribution, then any Derivative Works that You distribute must include a readable copy of the attribution notices contained within such NOTICE file […]

So yes, you must provide a copy of the license with the source code *and* with compiled binaries. You also mustn't delete existing attribution notices from the source code. Also, you must forward a `NOTICE` file if it exists. If you fulfil these conditions, you can copy the library and distribute it to your client.

The patent stuff in the license is irrelevant for you if you don't own any patents regarding this software, but is important so that you and your client can use this software without inadvertently infringing on any author's patents. Event though, you do have to copy the license!

Comment: Thank you so much for help reading this.  I found myself confused when trying to understand the difference between modifications to the library and the library itself.